# How to return an array from function using java

Tags: java

[image]

i wrote a program to get the address details from user and print the same without using 2 for loops, so i used function **add_show()**.
but i am getting **error as string[] cannot be converted to string.
return add;**

```
public String add_show()
{ 

    Scanner h=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of address to deliver");
    int n=h.nextInt();
    String[] add=new String[n];
    System.out.println("Enter the"+n+" of address to deliver");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        add[i]=h.next();
    }
    return add;
}

public void show()
{
     System.out.println("Book name is "+B_name());
     System.out.println("count "+department());
     System.out.println("address is "+add_show());
}
```

please update ,how to get returned value of array from function.

Comment: change the return type of the method ... `public String[] add_show()` and also check the standard notation in java. `add_show` is not standard.

Comment: return type should be Array - String[]

Comment: Unrelated: 1. Please add Error messages / stack traces as text. 2. Please properly indent your code snippets. 3. You really should comply to Java code conventions (naming of variables, methods ... ) ; All this makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set the correct return type to return an array :

```
public String[] add_show()
```

Then, to print the result, I would suggest you to not print directly the result of the method, store them.

```
System.out.println("Book name is "+B_name());
System.out.println("count "+department());
System.out.println("address is "+add_show());
```

Would look like

```
String bookName = B_name();
String count = department();
String[] addresses = add_show();

System.out.println("Book name is " + bookName);
System.out.println("count " + count);
System.out.println("address is " + addresses);
```

Now, if you try to print an array directly, it will look like `[String@...`, you need to get the content yourself, or use a method that will do it...

Using `Arrays.toString`, it will return a formatted `String` like "[value1, value2, value3, ... valueN]", not perfect for a user

```
String addressesFormat = Arrays.toString(addresses);
```

You can used since Java 8 the `String.join` to join every content with a specific delimiter :

```
String addressesFormat = String.join("\n", addresses);
```

Then print the result :

```
System.out.println("address is " + addressesFormat);
```

FYI: You should check the Java standard notation, a method should not have `_` in his name, it should used camelCase to look like `addShow`.

Comment: @Keerthana be aware that only one answer can be accepted (I notice you have change the accepted answer to mine), if you want to thanks more than one answer, you can upvote them, but can only accept the one that match your need. If this is mine, thanks ;) if not, this is fine to me.

Comment: i thanked for changing the code alignment.  i am new to java hope u find it. so i got it more about the coding in your explanation

Answer (score 5):

```
public String[] add_show()
{
    Scanner h=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of address to deliver");
    int n=h.nextInt(); 
    String[] add=new String[n];
    System.out.println("Enter the"+n+" of address to deliver");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      add[i]=h.next();
    }
    return add;
}
```

Change the return type of the method to a string array, it would work for you.

Comment: i did that too..but the whole function is running based on the number of count times.ex: if count is 2 then add_show is running 2 times

Comment: @Keerthana If the method runs twice, then you have code elsewhere that does that

Comment: enter image description here.i made the changes but it's not working properly, i have added error screenshot into my question(.enter image description here) .please check it

Comment: "s" is not an int ... @Keerthana I personally would take input as string and then validate it first instead of using nextInt. Or at least try/catch it. Never trust user input.

Comment: @Keerthana try using  return Arrays.toString(add) and changing the function type back to String instead of String[]

Comment: thanks alot..its working by changing the return type

Comment: @Keerthana you're welcome, It would be great if you could accept my answer! Happy Coding!!

Comment: @Farhan Qasim...i am getting error as [LJava.lang.String;@3232]while using this  public String[] add_show(). can you pleas clarify??

Comment: @Keerthana This is not an error, this is explain in my answer. Printing an array dosen't work like this.

Comment: @AxelH..yes i understood...code is perfectly working...thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

The return type must be String[], the "[]" means array of, if you declare String as result type, you must return a String.

Answer (score 0):

- `public String add_show(){...}` means that the function will return an object of type `String`
- you want to return an `array` of `String`, you need to change to `public String[] add_show(){...}`

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 you can do this with your add_show return:

```
String.join(delimiter, elements);
```

So it would be:

```
public String add_show(){
    ...
    return String.join(",", add);
}
```

Comment: thanks alot,,it's working .but can you please tell me how it will work

Comment: It works, even if this is not directly what was ask "_How to return an array from function using java_". Sometime, it is not possible to change a requirement.